# Using threading to make web requests/scrape data, seems list storing result is being overwritten somewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape data from yellowpages.com, they keep a list of cities starting with a certain letter in a certain state at the following url `https://www.yellowpages.com/state-<state-abbreviation>?page=<letter>`, so all cities in New York starting with the letter 'c' would be `https://www.yellowpages.com/state-ny?page=c`, for example.

Ultimately, I'm trying to write every city, state combo to a variable, `locations`, and then to a file. When I initially went to do this, I just built the list of urls, looped over and sent one request at a time. This was taking forever so I discovered threading and am trying to implement that.

When I run this program, the logging code I added shows it making a request to all 1300  pages(50 states*26 letters), but only the last state in my `states` variable, Wyoming, gets written to the file. It will write cities A-Z for the state of Wyoming to a file, but nothing else.

My code:

```
def get_session():
    if not hasattr(thread_local, 'session'):
        thread_local.session = requests.Session()
    return thread_local.session

def download_site(url):
    """ Make request to url and scrape data using bs4"""
    session = get_session()
    with session.get(url) as response:
        logging.info(f"Read {len(response.content)} from {url}")
        scrape_data(response)

def download_all_sites(urls):
    """ call download_site() on list of urls"""
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 50) as executor:
        executor.map(download_site, urls)


def scrape_data(response):
    """uses bs4 to get city, state combo from yellowpages html and appends to global locations list"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    ul_elements = soup.find_all('ul')
    for ul_element in ul_elements:
        anchor_elements = ul_element.find_all('a')
        for element in anchor_elements:
            locations.append(element.text + ',' + state_abbrieviated)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    urls = [] # will hold yellowpages urls
    locations = [] # will hold scraped 'city, state' combinations,  modified by scrape_data() function 

    states = {
        'AK': 'Alaska',
        'AL': 'Alabama',
        'AR': 'Arkansas',
        'AZ': 'Arizona',
        'CA': 'California',
        'CO': 'Colorado',
        'CT': 'Connecticut',
        'DC': 'District of Columbia',
        'DE': 'Delaware',
        'FL': 'Florida',
        'GA': 'Georgia',
        'HI': 'Hawaii',
        'IA': 'Iowa',
        'ID': 'Idaho',
        'IL': 'Illinois',
        'IN': 'Indiana',
        'KS': 'Kansas',
        'KY': 'Kentucky',
        'LA': 'Louisiana',
        'MA': 'Massachusetts',
        'MD': 'Maryland',
        'ME': 'Maine',
        'MI': 'Michigan',
        'MN': 'Minnesota',
        'MO': 'Missouri',
        'MS': 'Mississippi',
        'MT': 'Montana',
        'NC': 'North Carolina',
        'ND': 'North Dakota',
        'NE': 'Nebraska',
        'NH': 'New Hampshire',
        'NJ': 'New Jersey',
        'NM': 'New Mexico',
        'NV': 'Nevada',
        'NY': 'New York',
        'OH': 'Ohio',
        'OK': 'Oklahoma',
        'OR': 'Oregon',
        'PA': 'Pennsylvania',
        'RI': 'Rhode Island',
        'SC': 'South Carolina',
        'SD': 'South Dakota',
        'TN': 'Tennessee',
        'TX': 'Texas',
        'UT': 'Utah',
        'VA': 'Virginia',
        'VT': 'Vermont',
        'WA': 'Washington',
        'WI': 'Wisconsin',
        'WV': 'West Virginia',
        'WY': 'Wyoming'
    }
    letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
               'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    # build list of urls that need to be scrape
    for state_abbrieviated ,state_full in states.items():
        for letter in letters:
            url = f'https://www.yellowpages.com/state-{state_abbrieviated}?page={letter}'
            urls.append(url)

    # scrape data
     download_all_sites(urls)
     logging.info(f"\tSent/Retrieved {len(urls)} requests/responses in {duration} seconds")

     # write data to file
     with open('locations.txt','w') as file:
     for location in locations:
        file.write(location + '\n')
```

So given that only the last state gets written to the file, it seems my `locations` list variable is being overwritten every time the code moves to scrape data for a new state?

The question to this title is vague because I've stared and thought about this for awhile now and I am not too sure where the problem is/ I don't know what I don't know. I'm not sure if this is an issue with threading or if I messed up somewhere else. Anyway, if anyone looks at this and can spot the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening file in write mode deletes it's content. Change flag to 'a' or 'a+'. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/9256726

*My opinion: try to save each state into separate file and merge them after all pages successfully scrap.*

Also, try multithreading instead of threading, beacuse it doesn't solve performance issues (threads are sharing global lock). There is a good video why and how you can do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7vBbelRXn0